# Bootstrap carousel stop cycling when some event occur

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Using Bootstrap carousel i had a problem with stopping auto cycle.

It is said in documentation, that if set interval:false, carousel won't auto cycle, but there is nothing said what to do, when you need to stop auto cycle when some event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

lets say we have this code at project

```
$('#carousel-images').carousel({
    interval: 5000,
    pause : 'hover'
});
```

Then we have some click event handler, that should do two things

First: n-th slide should be set

Second: auto-slide should stop

```
$('.smallSlide').click(function(e) {
    $('#carousel-images').carousel(4);
    $('#carousel-images').carousel('pause');
}
```

This code won't do the trick, because 'pause' will be tried to be set at the moment of slide being slided.

This will work for you:

```
$('.smallSlide').click(function(e) {
    $('#carousel-images').carousel(4);
        $('#carousel-images').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
        $('#carousel-images').carousel('pause');
    });
}
```